# Cell content not being displayed UITableView, in Xcode with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView whose cells are created programmatically and are infinite, so not static. The data for the cells is not being displayed, however when I press them they work perfectly. So just the labels are not being displayed. How do you show a label in a cell in Swift 2.0. I didnt create the app myself, I am just doing testing, so I do not know where to look. If someone can post the code to create a label in a cell, I can search that in the application and find out what is going wrong. Thank you.

Here is the method that is responsible for showing the data in a cell.

```
- (void) displayAlertData:(NSDictionary *) aAlertDict {

      self.lblInfo.text = @"Microsoft Conference Room MPR2";

       NSArray *timeInfo = [[aAlertDict valueForKey:kALERT]     componentsSeparatedByString:@"Time:"];


      NSString *aImgName = nil;

      if ([[aAlertDict valueForKey:kSENSORTYPE] isEqualToString:kSensorMotion]) {
              self.lblSensType.text = @"Motion Sensor";
    //        self.lblDate.text = [self monthNameFromDate:[timeInfo objectAtIndex:1]];

        if ([[aAlertDict valueForKey:kisChecked] isEqualToString:@"True"]) {

        aImgName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"motion_icon_gray" ofType:@"png"];
        }
        else {

           aImgName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"motion_icon" ofType:@"png"];
       }
    }
```

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: Yes posting code now. Also the code is in objective c has the project contians a combination of Objective c and Swift.

Comment: Looks like a dictionary filled with labels inside it. Self.lblInfo is the label itself

Comment: Is it not showing because the label is being created but not being added as a subview of the cell?

Comment: yes, i don't found any code for cell, you should add label in your tableview cell and check

Comment: Ok thank you will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the UITableView label can be set by multiple ways , check for the label in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method of UITableView :

1. cell.textlabel
2. create custom label

`var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
 label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
 label.text = "I'am a test label"
 cell.addsubview(label)`

3. Create custom cell in xib/storyboard and place label inside it

Hope this helps you to find the code